# The story of the Minim and Boethusians; trying to fix the festival of Shavuot on Sunday

Tags: history, sources-mekorot, calendar, shavuos, non-rabbinic-judaism

I've found different sources like the Mishnah, Babylonian Talmud (tractate Rosh HaShanah), Jerusalem Talmud, Tosefta etc., talking about the Minim and the Boethusians who wanted to fix the festival of Shavuot the day after the Shabbat, i.e. on Sunday.

I would really like to know what are the earliest sources known about this topic, and what's the whole story behind this.

Please, feel free to edit.

Comment: To clarify: They wanted the first day of sefirah to be on Sunday, because they took the Torah literally when it said ממחרת השבת, they didn't care when Shavuos was

Comment: @user613 thank you: Rabbi Nehorai bar Shinai, a tanna of the fourth generation, states: It happened that I went down to give evidence of a certain witness in Ushah, and they did not need me, but I sought a pretext to visit my fellows. And what was the evil there? **That they used to say Atzeret followed the Shabbat** and they used to go out on it while it was still evening, taking it for granted that it would be sanctified…  A quote related to the evil doings of the Minim and Boethusians, that shows that the date of Shavuot did matter, main issue tough was the change of the start of sefirah.

Comment: @user613 I'm sure the minim/Sadducees thought that we were the ones who didn't care when Shavuot actually was and they accused us od changing the date

Comment: The Boethusians who were talking about the _minim_ also wanted to _Shavuos_ to be Sunday?

Comment: Are you familiar with the ATBASH for the calendar? Could it be the cause, as they thought, of the calendar corruption? Like modern day "Watch Tower" sect/minim think it is, so they are calculating their own so called "14th of nissan".
Take a look at this article https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_the_Jewish_Calendar/The_Atbash
A gittn shabes.

Comment: @UlrikheLukoie Atbash is irrelevant. The whole case of the baytusim was way before Hillel hasheni made the calendar we use nowadays

Comment: @Levi I looked up the Gemoro, and Rashi does mention the 1st day of sefirah and Shavuos. Do you're right

Comment: I count the omer according to the Halacha, but found it strange others teach otherwise. So i tried to get the picture behind these idea´s and find a source on which most of the statements are based that the ´counting would start a day after a shabbat in stead of the second Yom Tov of Pesach. Than i came across this fascinating story, that shows us such an issue accured earlier in history, a story that shows how certain groups claimed that the omer should be counted on a different date, a story that shows there was something wrong with that, and confirms todays counting of the omer.